# Returning List<int> from Database

Tags: c#, sql-server, list, executescalar

I have a simple problem that I have not been able to find an answer to despite much Googling. Perhaps posting this question up will help the next poor soul who looks for the same answer.

I have a query that returns a collection of distinct ID's.

I am creating an `SQLCommand` with this query and using `ExecuteScalar( )` to run it.

`ExecuteScalar( )` appears to return an object and will not allow me to cast it to List.

What is the best practice to fix this and how can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

execute scalar returns a single piece of data. think one row, one column. if you want to return a collection you need to call `ExecuteReader()`. this will return an `IDataReader`. you can then iterate over the records and return you list.

Answer (score 3):

[ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx):

> Executes the query, and returns the **first column of the first row** in the result set returned by the query. **Additional columns or rows are ignored**.

You need to use [SqlDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqldatareader.aspx):

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection);
IList<int> ints = new List<int>();
using(SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader()) {
     while (reader.Read())
     {
         ints.add(reader.GetInt32(0)); // provided that first (0-index) column is int which you are looking for
     }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteScalar(` ) - return only first row and first column....

Check msdn : [SqlCommand.ExecuteScalar](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar.aspx)

You need to user something like this to get result i.e [ExecuteReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y6wy5a0f.aspx)

```
 using (IDataReader reader = 
        command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection))
 {
      List<int> intlist = ReadList(reader);
 }
```

method to create list

```
List<int> ReadList(IDataReader reader)
{
    List<int> list = new List<int>();
    int column = reader.GetOrdinal("MyColumn");

    while (reader.Read())
    {
        //check for the null value and than add 
        if(!SqlReader.IsDBNull(column))
             list.Add(reader.GetInt32(column));
    }

    return list;
}
```

Comment: this will throw if a null db value is returned.

Comment: @JasonMeckley - thanks for pointing that i just improved code ............

Comment: no problem. I've run into this on more than one occasion

Answer (score 2):

`ExecuteScalar` method returns the first column of the first row in the result set returned by the query. Additional columns or rows are ignored.

If you want to have a list of items, You should use `ExecuteReader` and loop thru the reader and read the value needed

```
List<int> items=new List<int>();
using (IDataReader reader = db.ExecuteReader(dbCommand))
{
      while (reader.Read())
      {
         items.Add(reader.GetInt32(reader.GetOrdinal("YourColumnName"));
      }
}
```